Why are gubernatorial elections more likely to stray from statewide party trends?
I've noticed a pattern that it seems more likely that a reliably "blue" state may elect a Republican governor or a reliably "red" state may elect a Democratic governor. This surprises me. It seems like what party a state tends to elect to the senate and what party a state tends to vote for in the presidential election is much more likely to be strongly correlated, but when it comes to the governor, it doesn't seem to really matter.
Here are two concrete examples I've plumbed from the depths of wikipedia:

Kentucky is a "red" state. They have only voted for a Democrat for president in two elections since 1980. But their governor is currently Andy Beshear, a Democrat. They have only elected two Republicans for governor since 1972.
Wikipedia says of Vermont:


Historically, Vermont was considered one of the most reliably Republican states in the country in terms of national elections. From 1856 to 1988, Vermont voted Democratic only once, in Lyndon B. Johnson's landslide victory of 1964 against Barry M. Goldwater.
...
After narrowly supporting George H. W. Bush in 1988, it gave Democrat Bill Clinton a 16-point margin in 1992—the first time the state had gone Democratic since 1964. Vermont has voted Democratic in every presidential election since.

And yet their gubernatorial elections have been essentially 50-50 over the same time range of 1992-2020, with the current trend swinging hard R. In the last 4 gubernatorial elections, Republicans won by 8.7, 14.9, 41.1, and 45.8 points! Which is in my opinion, astonishing.
What causes this trend?

Probably Maryland is better example in the 2nd category. https://www.nga.org/former-governors/maryland/

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I don't know if that's the best example. That looks pretty solidly blue to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_Maryland

Gubernatorial elections are about a single person. And maybe governors are seen more like simple executives where party politics doesn't really play a role.

Well, you only looked at Vermont since 1992. Maryland had 2 R and 2 D governors since then. Seems 50/50 also. I guess you only care why 'red' states have D governor somtimes?

Just to be clear: by "red state" and "blue state" you only mean which party got the majority for the presidential election?

I feel like 538 covered this at one point, but all I can find right now are mentions that there isn't a correlation, not any analysis of why there isn't.  See the paragraph that has footnote #3 here, for an example.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever No, I'm interested in examples that go in either direction. I just didn't think that Maryland is the best example. Although I suppose part of that comes down to whether you're counting # of elections won by a party vs # of governors from either party. So yes, by that second metric, MD is a fine example. I will also admit that I may be cherry picking a little bit because I'm specifically looking for examples that demonstrate what I'm asking about. KY and VT are probably the two most extreme examples I could find.

@MisterMiyagi By " state" I am meaning "states which are reliably expected to vote for a certain party for president", although I think senate party history is another facet of this. But that is also part of my question: Senate and presidential party preference seems to align more strongly then presidential and gubernatorial, or senate and gubernatorial do. I'm also not really considering representatives since that gets very muddied by districts. When it comes to reps, most states are essentially "purple"

I distinctly remember an Economist article 4-5 years back that started out by stating that voters at the state level often aimed for competency and getting things done from their governors and that therefore the winners of that position were more on merit than partisan association.  However, iirc, the article then segued into main subject matter.  No sources were cited, but whoever wrote it covers American politics professionally so could be expected to be knowledgeable.

If Massachusetts is a good example, the reason may be that the governor's party affiliation is not as significant as the legislators'. Democrats hold supermajorities in both the state House of Representatives and Senate. This makes them veto-proof, so the governor can't exert too much control.
In recent decades MA has had several Republican governors: Bill Weld (1991-1997), Paul Cellucci (1997-2001), Jane Swift (acting, 2001-2003), Mitt Romney (2003-2007), and Charlie Baker (2015-2023). They were all considered moderate Republicans. Romney is a prime example: from his Wikipedia entry:

Romney was the lone Republican to vote to convict Donald Trump in his first impeachment trial, making him the first senator ever to have voted to remove a president of the same party from office.[5] Romney also voted to convict in Trump's second trial in 2021. He marched alongside Black Lives Matter protestors, voted to confirm both Amy Coney Barrett and Ketanji Brown Jackson to the Supreme Court, supported gun control measures, and did not vote for Trump in the 2016 and 2020 presidential elections. He has long been hawkish on issues such as Iran, China, and Russia, and is one of Israel's staunchest supporters in Congress. He has been accused by Trump loyalists of being a Republican In Name Only.

If the governor can't exert control based on party ideology, the people can elect them based on personality rather than affiliation.

Several Forces Contribute
Without getting into the claim that this is a pattern, per se, as that involves context-driven analyses:
Voters Frequently Prefer Divided Government.
"Divided Government" refers to any state where one party/entity has control over some portion of the government, but is forced to share power with an opposing party or entity.  In the US this can mean different parties control the House and Senate, or one party controls both but their opposition controls the Presidency, or even refer to a President of one party having to contend with a deep judicial bench appointed by their opponents.  The gist is: The only way to get things done is for the parties to cooperate where they're able to stomach it.
Even in our 'more polarized age,' this isn't necessarily a death knell for getting meaningful policy work done, though that certainly can be an outcome.
Voters' preferences for divided vs. unified government will vary over time, and especially depending on what they see the likely possibilities to be.  Part of the American tradition, however, is a deep skepticism of unchecked governmental power and divided governments are the gold standard for checked power - many proponents of divided government see a presumed policy gridlock as a good thing.
Statewide offices bypass numerous incumbency advantages.
Gubernatorial races are, by definition, statewide. This means that while a given party may have a broad - even dominating - support on a structural basis, these are often the product of historical trends and prior rounds of efforts to solidify political power. The most extreme and illustrative of this is Jerrymandering.
Gubernatorial races are immune to district-cooking, and allow both parties to push their efforts into a single race, aiming to mobilize the totality of their bases.  The party with a dominant position, however, must now also mobilize to defend that dominance (lest the minority party be allowed to make gains from down-ballot effects), while the minority party is able to be more focused in its own efforts.
Governors don't need to fear party/caucus leadership.
Senators, the other statewide office for a given state, must balance not only how they appeal to their voters - but also constrain themselves in ways amenable to the party leadership and peers with whom they will be required to work. A Senator is not a stand-alone representative in the same way that a Governor is.  As such, Governors are able to appeal to opposite-party voters in ways that would be damaging to Senators.  Moreover, the governorship is a powerful route to gaining structural dominance, or weakening the dominance of the incumbent majority party. Both cause the minority party to fight very hard in ways that they don't need to/can't afford to for Senate seats.
